# Backbone Sub-View for List

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am having a hard time understanding sub-views with Backbone and am trying to learn how to use them.

I want to create a simple unordered list using a main view for the container, and a sub-view for each list item.

Here is a Fiddle to what I have currently: http://jsfiddle.net/LrZrJ/

Here is the HTML I want to see in the end:

```
<div class="js-container">
    <h3>Stat = ok</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>Hello world</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var TheModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    default: {
        photos: '',
        stat: ''   
    }
});

var TheCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TheModel,

    url: 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?page=1&api_key=a2978e5ce30c337e3b639172d3e1a0d1&tags=candy&method=flickr.photos.search&per_page=3&format=json&jsoncallback=?'

});

// The main view
var List = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new TheCollection();

        this.item = new ListItem();

        return this;
    },

    render: function () {
        var self = this;

        this.collection.fetch({
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                var listTemplate = _.template( $('#listContainer').html(), {
                    collection: self.collection.toJSON()
                });

                self.$el.html(listTemplate);
                self.$el.html( self.item.render() );
            }
        });

        return this;
    }

});

var ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var itemTemplate = _.template( $('#item').html(), {} );

        return itemTemplate;
    }

});

var myList= new List();
myList.render();
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<script type="text/template" id="listContainer">
    <h3>Stat = <%- collection[0].stat %></h3>
    <ul>

    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="item">
    <li>Hello world</li>
</script>

<div class="js-container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. You have two problems right here:

```
self.$el.html(listTemplate);
self.$el.html( self.item.render() );
```

First of all, jQuery's [`html` function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-htmlString) replaces everything:

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content.

That means that your second `.html` call:

```
self.$el.html( self.item.render() );
```

overwrites everything from the first one. You probably want to use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead, that will just add the `<li>` to whatever you `append` to. You'll also want to `append` to the `<ul>`, not the `self.$el`; Backbone includes a handy [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) function in your view's for searching within the view's `el`:

> **$ (jQuery)** `view.$(selector)`
>
> [...] It's equivalent to running: view.$el.find(selector)

So to find the `<ul>` and put the `<li>` inside it, you can say this:

```
self.$('ul').append(self.item.render())
```

While I'm here, it is common for a view's `render` to `return this` and then the caller would `something.append(v.render().el)` to get the view onto the page. You could use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to replace the sub-view's `el` with your `<li>` from the template:

```
var ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function () {
        var itemTemplate = _.template( $('#item').html(), {} );
        this.setElement(itemTemplate);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and then `self.$('ul').append(self.item.render().el)` in the parent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/JHV9w/1/

An alternative would be to add `tagName: 'li'` to `ListItem` so that Backbone would create an `<li>` as that view's `el` and then remove the `<li>...</li>` from the template. That would give you a `ListItem` like this:

```
var ListItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    render: function () {
        var itemTemplate = _.template( $('#item').html(), {} );
        this.$el.html(itemTemplate);
        return this;
    }
});
```

and an `#item` template like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="item">
    Hello world
</script>
```

This structure would (IMO) be more standard than what you're currently working with (but Backbone isn't very opinionated so do what works for you).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/DVFVT/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks so much!  I was making something that contains everything in a single View but thought that it would be nice to have sub-views to break it up.  I saw that the jQuery .html() was overwriting the first template, but was stuck on how to overcome that.  Thank you!